# Conky and conky-manager on Juno?

Tags: release-juno, software-installation, conky

Last year, I had successfully installed conky and conky-manager in Freya. Now I have migrated to Juno. I am very happy with this new version. But I would like to install also conky and conky-manager. I know it's not easy, but you can, and I have not found complete and effective instructions on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all download files from following links:

1. [Realpath_8.26](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/340091846/realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb)
2. [Newer release version](https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases)

And then go to your download directory use following commands in your terminal:

1. `sudo apt install conky`
2. `sudo dpkg -i realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.deb`
3. `sudo apt -f install`

Enjoy!